# Get data from MYSQL to Power BI: "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream"

Tags: mysql, powerbi

I'm trying to get data from MYSQL to Power BI.

After I enter the server and database name, I get this message "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream"

Did anyone encounter it before?

Thanks in advance

[image: The error]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an out of date MySQL Connector/NET driver on the system running Power BI

You can get the latest version from: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/